# how to use a custom view in a xml file in android

Tags: android, xml

here is my xml  in which i am using my custom view . that view is in another package named com.soft.MyView and the class which is extending view is also named MyView now m getting force close and the error in logcat is   07-21 16:26:29.936: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19854): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.soft.MyView.MyView  ..plss tell me where am i wrong??

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<com.soft.MyView.MyView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="187dp" android:id="@+id/drawingImageView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my class MyView

```
    public class MyView extends View{



class Pt{

    float x, y;



    Pt(float _x, float _y){

        x = _x;

        y = _y;

    }

}



Pt[] myPath = { new Pt(100, 100),

                new Pt(200, 200),

                new Pt(200, 500),

                new Pt(400, 500),

                new Pt(400, 200)

                };



    public MyView(Context context) {

        super(context);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }



    @Override

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onDraw(canvas);





        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Path path = new Path();



        path.moveTo(myPath[0].x, myPath[0].y);

        for (int i = 1; i < myPath.length; i++){

            path.lineTo(myPath[i].x, myPath[i].y);

        }

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);



    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the reason for your problem is that you used only the code-version CTOR:

  [public View (Context context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View%28android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet%29)

  quote from android developers guide:

  > Simple constructor to use when creating a view from code.
- the solution would be to add all of the possible CTORs that the custom view needs for the layout inflating process, or at least this one:

  [public View (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View%28android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet%29)

  quote from android developers guide:

  > Constructor that is called when inflating a view from XML. This is
  >   called when a view is being constructed from an XML file, supplying
  >   attributes that were specified in the XML file. This version uses a
  >   default style of 0, so the only attribute values applied are those in
  >   the Context's Theme and the given AttributeSet.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax    `<yourcompletepackagename.YourCustomClassName ..../>`

```
<com.soft.MyView 
          ^^^^^^
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:layout_marginTop="187dp" 
android:id="@+id/drawingImageView"/>
```

Comment: Please read it again the OP has mentioned that he is having `com.soft.MyView` package name and `MyView` as class name.

Comment: my complete package name is com.soft.MyView  and my class is MyView

Comment: try to rename package name and if possible use `com.soft.myview` instead of `com.soft.MyView`

Comment: nw i have posted my class even ..if u can help??

Answer (score 0):

You need to override a different constructor in MyView. Instead of having just this constructor:

```
public MyView(Context context) {
   super(context);
}
```

When you create a custom View, you need to at least override this one too:

```
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
}
```